# Upload notepad data and insert into SQL database

Tags: c#, notepad

I have proximity reader and it gives me data like this. It's the in out data of my company's employees.

010:0007739166:20120908:071009:BLANK !!:11
010:0013646521:20120908:073125:BLANK !!:11
010:0010840695:20120908:073129:BLANK !!:11
010:0005546931:20120908:073131:BLANK !!:11
010:0013656129:20120908:073136:BLANK !!:11
010:0010827749:20120908:073222:BLANK !!:11
010:0009668536:20120908:073251:BLANK !!:11
010:0009673161:20120908:073410:BLANK !!:11
010:0010822274:20120908:073421:BLANK !!:11
010:0005530871:20120908:073532:BLANK !!:11
010:0009299793:20120908:073636:BLANK !!:11
010:0009679185:20120908:073638:BLANK !!:11
010:0002760233:20120908:073652:BLANK !!:11
010:0007740048:20120908:073703:BLANK !!:11
010:0009674566:20120908:073717:BLANK !!:11
010:0010844728:20120908:073727:BLANK !!:11
010:0005545384:20120908:073742:BLANK !!:11
010:0010848020:20120908:073824:BLANK !!:11
010:0002008128:20120908:073857:BLANK !!:11
010:0010826526:20120908:073903:BLANK !!:11
010:0007707930:20120908:073923:BLANK !!:11
010:0010844804:20120908:073927:BLANK !!:11
010:0000711020:20120908:073931:BLANK !!:11
010:0009671072:20120908:073943:BLANK !!:11
010:0009293595:20120908:073958:BLANK !!:11
010:0013653569:20120908:074001:BLANK !!:11
010:0009662322:20120908:074006:BLANK !!:11
010:0010830931:20120908:074009:BLANK !!:11
010:0010820791:20120908:074013:BLANK !!:11
010:0009667635:20120908:074015:BLANK !!:11
010:0010834564:20120908:074018:BLANK !!:11
010:0009680581:20120908:074023:BLANK !!:11

The first thing before : I don't know what it is. 2nd thing is employee's card no. 3rd thing is date, 4th thing is time.

I need to insert my SQL database table with this type of data. I do not have any idea how to insert them. Please help me. :). thanks u guyz in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SqlBulkInsert` , in order to insert your datas

```
BULK INSERT 
   [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . | schema_name . ] [ table_name | view_name ] 
      FROM 'data_file' 
     [ WITH 
    ( 
   [ [ , ] BATCHSIZE = batch_size ] 
   [ [ , ] CHECK_CONSTRAINTS ] 
   [ [ , ] CODEPAGE = { 'ACP' | 'OEM' | 'RAW' | 'code_page' } ] 
   [ [ , ] DATAFILETYPE = 
      { 'char' | 'native'| 'widechar' | 'widenative' } ] 
   [ [ , ] FIELDTERMINATOR = 'field_terminator' ] 
   [ [ , ] FIRSTROW = first_row ] 
   [ [ , ] FIRE_TRIGGERS ] 
   [ [ , ] FORMATFILE = 'format_file_path' ] 
   [ [ , ] KEEPIDENTITY ] 
   [ [ , ] KEEPNULLS ] 
   [ [ , ] KILOBYTES_PER_BATCH = kilobytes_per_batch ] 
   [ [ , ] LASTROW = last_row ] 
   [ [ , ] MAXERRORS = max_errors ] 
   [ [ , ] ORDER ( { column [ ASC | DESC ] } [ ,...n ] ) ] 
   [ [ , ] ROWS_PER_BATCH = rows_per_batch ] 
   [ [ , ] ROWTERMINATOR = 'row_terminator' ] 
   [ [ , ] TABLOCK ] 
   [ [ , ] ERRORFILE = 'file_name' ] 
    )]
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms188365.aspx

Comment: I'am hhappy to help you Bappy